# Intercat JS doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, draggable

I would like to use [Interact JS](http://interactjs.io/).

For getting started, I have use the demo code on this website.

However, however it does not work.
The script is loaded but the elements are not movable as a demonstration . I have the following code :

```js
/* The dragging code for '.draggable' from the demo above
 * applies to this demo as well so it doesn't have to be repeated. */

// enable draggables to be dropped into this
interact('.dropzone').dropzone({
  // only accept elements matching this CSS selector
  accept: '#yes-drop',
  // Require a 75% element overlap for a drop to be possible
  overlap: 0.75,

  // listen for drop related events:

  ondropactivate: function (event) {
    // add active dropzone feedback
    event.target.classList.add('drop-active');
  },
  ondragenter: function (event) {
    var draggableElement = event.relatedTarget,
        dropzoneElement = event.target;

    // feedback the possibility of a drop
    dropzoneElement.classList.add('drop-target');
    draggableElement.classList.add('can-drop');
    draggableElement.textContent = 'Dragged in';
  },
  ondragleave: function (event) {
    // remove the drop feedback style
    event.target.classList.remove('drop-target');
    event.relatedTarget.classList.remove('can-drop');
    event.relatedTarget.textContent = 'Dragged out';
  },
  ondrop: function (event) {
    event.relatedTarget.textContent = 'Dropped';
  },
  ondropdeactivate: function (event) {
    // remove active dropzone feedback
    event.target.classList.remove('drop-active');
    event.target.classList.remove('drop-target');
  }
});
```

```css
#outer-dropzone {
  height: 140px;
}

#inner-dropzone {
  height: 80px;
}

.dropzone {
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: dashed 4px transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 10px auto 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 80%;
  transition: background-color 0.3s;
}

.drop-active {
  border-color: #aaa;
}

.drop-target {
  background-color: #29e;
  border-color: #fff;
  border-style: solid;
}

.drag-drop {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 40px;
  padding: 2em 0.5em;

  color: #fff;
  background-color: #29e;
  border: solid 2px #fff;

  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
          transform: translate(0px, 0px);

  transition: background-color 0.3s;
}

.drag-drop.can-drop {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #4e4;
}

JS Demo only
```

```html
<script src="http://code.interactjs.io/v1.2.6/interact.js"></script>


<div id="no-drop" class="draggable drag-drop"> #no-drop </div>

<div id="yes-drop" class="draggable drag-drop"> #yes-drop </div>

<div id="outer-dropzone" class="dropzone">
  #outer-dropzone
  <div id="inner-dropzone" class="dropzone">#inner-dropzone</div>
 </div>
```

Why this code doesn't work ? It's the demo code of the documentation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the draggable code from the previous example, read the comments on the top of the js code, and look at the example below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  interact('.draggable')
  .draggable({
    // enable inertial throwing
    inertia: true,
    // keep the element within the area of it's parent
    restrict: {
      restriction: "parent",
      endOnly: true,
      elementRect: { top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 1, right: 1 }
    },
    // enable autoScroll
    autoScroll: true,

    // call this function on every dragmove event
    onmove: dragMoveListener,
    // call this function on every dragend event
    onend: function (event) {
      var textEl = event.target.querySelector('p');

      textEl && (textEl.textContent =
        'moved a distance of '
        + (Math.sqrt(event.dx * event.dx +
                     event.dy * event.dy)|0) + 'px');
    }
  });

  function dragMoveListener (event) {
    var target = event.target,
        // keep the dragged position in the data-x/data-y attributes
        x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + event.dx,
        y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + event.dy;

    // translate the element
    target.style.webkitTransform =
    target.style.transform =
      'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';

    // update the posiion attributes
    target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
    target.setAttribute('data-y', y);
  }

  // this is used later in the resizing and gesture demos
  window.dragMoveListener = dragMoveListener;
  /* The dragging code for '.draggable' from the demo above
   * applies to this demo as well so it doesn't have to be repeated. */
  
  // enable draggables to be dropped into this
  interact('.dropzone').dropzone({
    // only accept elements matching this CSS selector
    accept: '#yes-drop',
    // Require a 75% element overlap for a drop to be possible
    overlap: 0.75,

    // listen for drop related events:

    ondropactivate: function(event) {
      // add active dropzone feedback
      event.target.classList.add('drop-active');
    },
    ondragenter: function(event) {
      var draggableElement = event.relatedTarget,
        dropzoneElement = event.target;

      // feedback the possibility of a drop
      dropzoneElement.classList.add('drop-target');
      draggableElement.classList.add('can-drop');
      draggableElement.textContent = 'Dragged in';
    },
    ondragleave: function(event) {
      // remove the drop feedback style
      event.target.classList.remove('drop-target');
      event.relatedTarget.classList.remove('can-drop');
      event.relatedTarget.textContent = 'Dragged out';
    },
    ondrop: function(event) {
      event.relatedTarget.textContent = 'Dropped';
    },
    ondropdeactivate: function(event) {
      // remove active dropzone feedback
      event.target.classList.remove('drop-active');
      event.target.classList.remove('drop-target');
    }
  });
})
```

```css
#outer-dropzone {
  height: 140px;
}

#inner-dropzone {
  height: 80px;
}

.dropzone {
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: dashed 4px transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 10px auto 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 80%;
  transition: background-color 0.3s;
}

.drop-active {
  border-color: #aaa;
}

.drop-target {
  background-color: #29e;
  border-color: #fff;
  border-style: solid;
}

.drag-drop {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 40px;
  padding: 2em 0.5em;

  color: #fff;
  background-color: #29e;
  border: solid 2px #fff;

  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
          transform: translate(0px, 0px);

  transition: background-color 0.3s;
}

.drag-drop.can-drop {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #4e4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/interact.js/1.2.6/interact.min.js"></script>


<div id="no-drop" class="draggable drag-drop">#no-drop</div>

<div id="yes-drop" class="draggable drag-drop">#yes-drop</div>

<div id="outer-dropzone" class="dropzone">
  #outer-dropzone
  <div id="inner-dropzone" class="dropzone">#inner-dropzone</div>
</div>
```